# Does Panache support pagination in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, pagination, quarkus-panache

Does Panache support pagination? I can't seem to find any related methods. I only found `.batchSize()`

After this call I'm working with an AggregateIterable. (http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/AggregateIterable.html)

```
MyPanacheMongoModel.mongoCollection().aggregate(Arrays.asList(sort1, group, sort2, project, replaceRoot))
```

I believe I could just add some more stages to my aggregation, but I was looking for a clean solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you have added all the other operations, you can add the `skip` and  `limit`  operation as well. Since you are executing an aggregation query by providing all the operations, it does not matter if it is Panache. It will be converted to bson and get executed.

Comment: Though the recommended / performant way is to track the last items sent and match their id and one other property and then order them